# Drawable with padding for Button with Icon and Text

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to have an icon and text on my custom button. I want both to be centered. For this Im using phillipcalvin-iconbutton. This works quite well however the drawable is set does not have any padding so it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to create another drawable with the same same resource that has a padding like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="3dp"
    android:left="3dp"
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="1dp">

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_done"
            >

            <padding
                android:left="50dp"
                android:top="50dp"
                android:right="50dp"
                android:bottom="50dp"
                />

        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
```

That does not make a difference.

I don't want to use some sort of Layout were I set a wrap a `TextView` and a `ImageView` because I loose the button animation.

Any Idea how I can solve this?

Just incase you want to see my custom button:

```
<ripple
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:color="@color/darkRipple">

<item android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp"     android:top="4dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/darkRipple" />
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp"          android:top="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/dark" />
        <size android:width="110dp" android:height="40dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

and here is how I use it:

```
<com.phillipcalvin.iconbutton.IconButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_dark"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_ic_done"
    app:iconPadding="10dp"
    android:text="DONE"
    android:textColor="@color/White"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to get around the problem could be to import the image used as a drawableLeft (android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_ic_done" in this case) to android studio as a new Image Asset. That'll allow you to set padding to the image at the time you import it(or you could set padding to the image using some external image editor).

Steps to achieve this:

- Right click res folder
- res -> new -> image asset
- [Customise the image       according to your needs][1]

  ```
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Weu6.png
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From official documrntation:

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.project.package"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
<!-- ... -->
<com.phillipcalvin.iconbutton.IconButton
android:id="@+id/search"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/action_search"
android:text="@string/search"
app:iconPadding="10dp" />
```

Comment: Do you mean the padding tag? Thats just for the padding between the icon and the text but not not for the icon in relation to the whole button...

Comment: iconPadding tag add padding around deawable(icon)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to tell me but If you are saying that iconPadding solves my problem: No it does not! As you can see I use iconPadding in my Code(Read my post) and you can see the result...

Comment: After investigation into code on this library's github I see that IconButton extends the android's Button and the logic of the padding is Button's logic. As advise you can use `android:padding="10dp"` of the android's Button but this will increase the button size/height. Additionally you can create your icon with transparency border. Or try to add size in `<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_done">`